# how to save the piped output to one array in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a cmdlet that gives output as below

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name
```

which outputs to

```
name
-----
group1
group 2
group3 
group 4
```

When I try to save it to the variable
like this

```
$output=Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name
```

then the variable outputs as below:

```
@{name=group1} @{name=group 2} @{name=group3} @{name=group43}
```

what I am trying to achieve is to save it in an array like

```
@('group1','groupSPACE2','group3','groupSPACE4')
```

can anyone help me to save it to the array in the desired fashion as in the last output

Comment: If the variable output looks like that, you have probably tried something like `"$output"` (note the double quotes) and PowerShell is _stringifying_ your objects. Just do `$output` or `$output.Name` depending on what you desire.

Comment: $output.name did the trick, Thank you